# adding bottomless tokens for rockshox Rock Shox 30 Gold Solo Air 100mm

Tags: mountain-bike, fork

Is it possible for me to purchase bottomless tokens for my fork without having to upgrade my fork?

I find I keep bottoming out my fork unless I put alot of air in it. At which point it's alittle harsh going down minior rocky decents.

If I do have to upgrade my fork, my problem is it will be expensive since I need to swap out  both my wheelset because they're qr 9mm and higher end shox tend to use maxles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, [RockShox](https://www.sram.com/rockshox/technologies/bottomless-tokens) doesn't list your fork as compatible with any of the Bottomless tokens.

However, they're just lumps of plastic that thread onto the bottom of the air-spring cap, you might well be able to find something from a 3rd party.

Comment: it's only paper says cj (GTA sanandreas reference). I will just upgrade my fork and get myself some grippy tires.

Comment: You might want to check if your front hub's axel can be changed to a through axel. Many manufacturers reuse shells and will sell you an upgrade kit.